# How do I add a gap between series in Highcharts Gantt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

I've got a Gantt chart:

[image]

And I'd like to add an horizontal gap between all series (1 and 2 in this case).

I've tried to use the [groupPadding](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.groupPadding) but with no success:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Gantt Chart with Progress Indicators'
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2']
  },
  xAxis: [{

    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    gridLineWidth: 1

  }, {

    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    gridLineWidth: 1

  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: "top",
        format: "{point.custom.label}"
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    groupPadding: 1,
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
      custom: {
        label: 1
      }
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
      custom: {
        label: 2
      }
    }]
  }, {
    groupPadding: 1,
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    data: [{
      y: 1,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
      custom: {
        label: 1
      }
    }, {
      y: 1,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
      custom: {
        label: 2
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fmcg/j4qehvcm/49/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding an empty category for an empty series and you will get a horizontal space between series.

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '', '2']
  },
  series: [{
    groupPadding: 1,
    type: 'line',
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
    }]
  }, {}, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [{
      y: 2,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
    }, {
      y: 2,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
    }]
  }]
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r6ugs493/

EDIT ----

A possible way to hide the vertical lines would be to hide them using the [yAxis.tickColor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickColor), [yAxis.lineColor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.lineColor) options.

And the table border can be rendered by [SVG Renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) to make the table complete by omitting the gaps between the series.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          series = chart.series,
          plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
          plotTop = chart.plotTop,
          plotWidth = chart.plotWidth;


        if (chart.myBackground) {
          chart.myBackground.destroy();
        }

        chart.myBackground = chart.renderer.rect(plotLeft - 40, plotTop, 40, 50, 0)
          .attr({
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: '#ccd6eb',
            opacity: 0.5,
            zIndex: 5
          })
          .add();
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '', '2'],
    tickColor: 'transparent',
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      //enabled: false
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not really a gap. I'd rather have a complete separation between series, instead of adding empty ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have a mechanism in Highcharts Gantt for adding gap spacing between rows, so I propose a workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian. any hints on how to remove the vertical yAxis grid lines just on those empty series? This way it would simulate perfectly.